# Install issue screen is balck

Tags: system-installation

I tried installing ubuntu 15. On my Lenovo pc but when I click install in the grub menu the screen just goes black.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar some years back with an Acer laptop. It came back to a hardware driver issue and I had to go to another screen, (by holding down ctrl-alt and pressing F1, F2, F3 or whatever), to find out what it was and stop the process to continue the installation.

Might be worth checking unless someone else knows better.